# Is there a way for docker to access host IP

Tags: docker

The host machine has an agent running on port 2000 I would like my docker running on bridge network sent data to the agent on the host machine. What changes do I have to do with the docker to that it can communicate with host,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share the entire host network stack with your container you can run it with Host Networking enabled by passing the following argument: `--network host`.

Documentation Summary: https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

And a tutorial: https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/

Some other options include:

1. Modifying the iptables rules on the host: `iptables -A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT`
2. [Routing all traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37536687/what-is-the-relation-between-docker0-and-eth0) to the `docker0` interface.