# What's the `docker0` there?

Tags: docker

I read document about `docker` network mode.

there display there are `docker0` and `eth1` on Host.

[image]

I have a question about it:
what's the `docker0`? is it an interface or bridge?
if is an interface, it should be have a IP address which can communicate with `172.17.0.2`, right?

Comment: It's an interface with a proper ip in the 172.17 subnet.

Comment: docker0 is a bridge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see for instance `docker0` described in [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20201109220442/https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/networking-your-docker-containers-using-docker0-bridge/):

> The docker0 bridge is virtual interface created by docker, it randomly chooses an address and subnet from the private range defined by RFC 1918 that are not in use on the host machine, and assigns it to `docker0`.
>
> All the docker containers will be connected to the docker0 bridge by default, the docker containers connnected to the `docker0` bridge could use the iptables NAT rules created by docker to communicate with the outside world.

[image: bridge]

> By default Docker will attach all containers to the docker0 bridge, so you do not need to specify any additional flag with docker run command to connect the docker containers to the `docker0` bridge, unless the `DOCKER_OPTS` in docker configuration file explicitly specifies to use the other network than `docker0` bridge, in this case you could use `–net=bridge` with docker run command to connect the containers to the `docker0` bridge.

See also "[What is the relation between `docker0` and `eth0`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37536687/6309)"